# How to store the value into NSMutableArray using button tags in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, tags, uibutton, nsmutablearray, store

I have 10 buttons, when clicks the buttons will increase the some amount of values. I want to put the values into NSMutableArray. But i don't want to add the values which depends on the button index, i want to add the values into the array as the same order (0 to ArrayCount) when clicks any button in randomly.

For Eg:

```
        switch (btn.tag) {
                       case 0:
                             itemValue = itemValue + 15;         //item value is 30
                             [amountArray addObject:itemValue];          
                             break;

                       case 1:
                             itemValue = itemValue + 30;          //item value is 60
                             [amountArray addObject:itemValue];          
                             break;

                       case 2:
                             itemValue = itemValue + 25;           //item value is 50
                             [amountArray addObject:itemValue];          
                             break;

                       case 3:
                             itemValue = itemValue + 40;            //item value is 80
                             [amountArray addObject:itemValue];          
                             break;

                        case 4:                        //item value is 45
                             itemValue = itemValue + 15; 
                             [amountArray addObject:itemValue];          
                             break;
```

In this case, i have clicked the button in the order of the button index 4,3,2,1,0 and expected result array is

```
                       {45,80,50,60,30}.
```

If i have used something like this,

```
         [amountArray replaceObjectAtIndex:btn.tag withObject:itemValue];
```

and the result is  {30,60,50,80,45}.

But i want to the store the values as normally in the array as 0 to arrayCount. When clicks the button every time, it will increase some value, so shouldn't allow the **duplicate values**, have to change only values.

Thanks!

Comment: I really don't understand your english. Can you go over and correct your question, It's hard to know what you want at this point.

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableSet will avoid dublicate.

so instead of using array just use NSMutableSet.

```
       NSMutableSet *amountSet=[[NSMutableSet alloc]init];   

       [amountSet addObject:itemValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an int to array that is wrong you need to use

```
[amountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:itemValue]];
```

Also you need to check if that value is available in array already by using the method of array

```
if([array indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:itemValue]] == NSNotFound) {
   //Add object here to mutable array
}
```

or not and later you need to sort array using sortDescripter or NSPredicate.